# Reactive Extensions Advice

Tags: system.reactive

Learning Reactive Extensions and I made a quick sample app, but I can't help feeling I'm not doing things correctly. (yes I know this is rather ambiguous but this is my first crack at rx)

The sample takes a file pattern and a search pattern then searches the file system for matches. The matches are then displayed as the line of text that included the match. Here is the search class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rummage
{
    internal class SearchEngine
    {
        private readonly Subject<SearchResult> searchResultsSubject = new Subject<SearchResult>();

        public IObservable<SearchResult> SearchResults
        {
            get { return searchResultsSubject.AsObservable(); }
        }

        private readonly Regex fileContentRegex;
        private readonly string filePattern;

        public SearchEngine(string filePattern, string fileContentPattern)
        {
            this.filePattern = filePattern;

            fileContentRegex = new Regex(".*" + fileContentPattern + ".*",
                RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        }

        public void SearchFolder(string path)
        {
            var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                var f = folder;
                Task.Run(() => SearchFolder(f));
            }

            var files = filePattern == null
                ? Directory.GetFiles(path)
                : Directory.GetFiles(path, filePattern);

            Parallel.ForEach(files,f=> Task.Run(() => SearchFile(f)));
        }

        private void SearchFile(string s)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(s)) return;

            var text = File.ReadAllText(s);
            var matches = fileContentRegex.Matches(text);

            if (matches.Count == 0) return;

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var result = new SearchResult
                {
                    Line = match.Value.Trim()
                };

                searchResultsSubject.OnNext(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's called from a window like so:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Rummage
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly SearchEngine engine;
        public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> SearchResults { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(SearchResults, SearchResults);
            DataContext = this;

            engine = new SearchEngine("*.cs", "namespace");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var obs = Observer.Create<SearchResult>(
                x =>
                {
                    lock (SearchResults)
                    {
                        SearchResults.Add(x);
                    }
                }
                );

            engine.SearchResults.Subscribe(obs);

            engine.SearchFolder("e:\\code");
        }
    }
}
```

Please forgive the hardcoding, it is just a sample app to get me familiar with things.

**My main questions:**

1. I have to lock the SearchResults ObservableCollection or I get threading issues. This seems wrong to me from what I've read about RX and leads me to think there is a better way to do this.
2. I'm basically updating the ObservableCollection on every OnNext call from the SearchEngine, thus the UI. I know there is a Throttle available but not sure how to use it in this scenario.
3. The Observer.Create call seems strange having to do that to pump the messages into an ObservableCollection, i'm sure there is a better way.

That plus any other tips you can give on how to improve this please do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're really going about this the wrong kind of way because when you work with Rx you should not be jumping back an forth from enumerables and tasks and you should avoid using subjects. Try to stay in the reactive space as much as possible.

Try this for `SearchEngine` class:

```
internal class SearchEngine
{
    private readonly Regex fileContentRegex;
    private readonly string filePattern;

    public SearchEngine(string filePattern, string fileContentPattern)
    {
        this.filePattern = filePattern;

        fileContentRegex = new Regex(".*" + fileContentPattern + ".*",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    }

    public IObservable<SearchResult> SearchFolder(string path)
    {
            Func<string, IObservable<string>> recurseFolders = null;
            recurseFolders = p =>
                Observable
                    .Return(p)
                    .Concat(
                        Directory
                            .EnumerateDirectories(p)
                            .ToObservable()
                            .SelectMany(d => recurseFolders(d)));

            var query =
                from d in recurseFolders(path)
                from f in
                (
                    filePattern == null
                        ? Directory.GetFiles(path)
                        : Directory.GetFiles(path, filePattern)
                ).ToObservable()
                from sr in SearchFile(f)
                select sr;

            return query;
    }

    private IObservable<SearchResult> SearchFile(string s)
    {
            return !File.Exists(s)
                ? Observable.Empty<SearchResult>()
                :
                    from text in Observable.Start(() => File.ReadAllText(s))
                    from match in fileContentRegex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().ToObservable()
                    select new SearchResult
                    {
                        Line = match.Value.Trim()
                    };
    }
}
```

There's no tasks and there's no subjects, and every time I've used a built-in function that returns an enumerable I've immediately converted it to an observable.

Also there's no separation from the call to search and the retrieving of the results - no `void` returns instead they return observables.

This version of the class should, I hope, be easier to read.

Now your main window class can look like this:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    private readonly SearchEngine engine;
    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> SearchResults { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>();
        engine = new SearchEngine("*.cs", "namespace");
    }

    public void Button_Click()
    {
        engine
            .SearchFolder("e:\\code")
            .ObserveOnDispatcher();
            .Subscribe(SearchResults.Add);
    }
}
```

I've simplified the class down a bit, but you should see what is going on. The key thin is that I've added the call to `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` which marshalls the observable to the UI thread and should eliminate any need for locks.

My code worked in my tests. Let me know how it goes you.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! Will give it a try.

Comment: That ObserveOnDispatcher is giving isn't being found by VS. I know it's in System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll and I don't seem to have that in my references. Any idea what nuget package contains that? I have core, interfaces, main, platform services and query.

Comment: @Kelly - Try nugetting `Rx-WPF`.